# Show equality of dimensions on linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $F: V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map and $U\subseteq W$ a linear subspace.

How do I proof that

$$
dim\left(F^{-1}\left(U\right)\right) = dim\left(U\; \cap \; Im\left(F\right)\right) + dim\left(Ker\left(F\right)\right)
$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_0=F^{-1}(U)$ , $W_0:=U$ and define the linear map $G:V_0 \to W_0$ by

$$G(x)=F(x).$$

Then we have:

$$ \dim V_0=\dim Im(G)+ \dim ker(G).$$

Its your turn to show that $Im(G)=U \cap Im(F)$ and $ker(G)=ker(F)$:

Comment: Thank you! I had this idea too but now I know how to write it down.